# compaq visual fortran on windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: fortran, windows-7-x64

how i can install compaq visual fortran on windows 7 64-bit?
it is not compatible with win64

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/2083-63-compaq-visual-fortran-64bit

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think so. According to Steve Lionel, of Powerstation/Digital/Compaq/Intel Fortran fame (the man's been at it for some time :) CVF has some trouble running on Win7. Not suprising, since it is a product whose development has been discontinued sometimes about 5 years ago.

My recommendation is that you upgrade to Intel Fortran, which is of the *same line*, meaning all your libraries (for example, for plotting on screen) will still be there. Their new product recently has introduced more than a few significant changes, and it is well worth it. Runs on VS2010 (full or shell) so you shouldn't have any trouble with it.

Comment: thanks, but i have a 7000 lines code to run, i can't translate it into intel fortran

Comment: I installed compaq visual fortran 6.1, and it was without any problem, but i run my code with 6.6 before, is there any diffrence bethween these versions? can i trust v6.1?

Comment: @Mojtaba - I have much more than that, or should i say - had - at the time of the switch. I don't remember having too much headaches with upgrading. Fortran is fortran, write once, run forever. Yes, there is quite a bit of diference between 6.1. and 6.6. (you'll have to see the release notes for the exact specs). Also, on 6.6. there were three service upgrades, A, B and C. But still, I stand by my advice - CVF is long unsupported. And Intel's is really one of the most quality products on the market today. If you need any specific help with the switch, post a question - I'll do my best to help.

Comment: @Mojtaba This is a common problem with legacy code. Sticking to Fortran standard minimizes problems when switching between compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what has been said, the Compaq Fortran 6 environment can be run within Windows 7 - 64 bits.
Personally, I ran the setupx86.exe file located in the X86 subdirectory of the CVF CD, but I specified that the files should be put into the Program Files (x86) directory. Then when I ran the Developer Studio and tried to compile a Fortran program. It said it did not find some libraries. So, within the CVF environment, I clicked on Tools/Options/Directories and told the program to get library, include,... files from the Program Files (x86) directory.
Then everything worked just swell !
If not, try to use the compatibilty option by right clicking on the Developer Studio icon.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your copy of Windows 7 is one of the higher end versions that supports it, you can install "Windows XP Mode" (really, a copy of Microsoft's virtual machine) and *probably* run it under that.